# Unbind an event with dojo on textbox

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, event-handling, dojo

I have a link "**prevBtn**" and I connect a customized tooltip to it "**previewBox**" where previewBox have a textbox and button inside that. When I try to add content to input box its not letting me for it. Its reverting to the click event. I want to add contents to my textbox.

```
this.addEvent(dojo.connect(prevBtn, 'click', this, function (evt) {
            console.log("Edit me");
            this.addTooltip(prevBtn);
        }));
```

---

```
  addTooltip: function(prevBtn) {        
        var previewBox = dojo.create('div', { className: 'prevBox'}, prevBtn);
        dojo.create("span", {className:"arrowUp"}, previewBox); 
        var input = new dijit.form.TextBox({
            required:true, 
            className: "previewInputBox",
            value: "",
            maxLength: 32,
            style: { width: 145+'px', height: 25+'px'}
        }).placeAt(previewBox);
                dojo.create("h3", {className:"borderBottom"}, previewBox);
        var byUser = new dijit.form.Button({
            label: "Preview",
            onClick: dojo.hitch(this, function() {
                //TODO
            })          
        }).placeAt(previewBox);                       
  },
```

I can provide more details if its any less for understanding. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To unbind the event after the forst click we need to follow the below code.

```
var handle =  this.addEvent(dojo.connect(prevBtn, 'click', this, function (evt) {
            console.log("Edit me");
            this.addTooltip(prevBtn);
            dojo.disconnect(handle);
        }));
```